# Xamarin Forms Disable swipe between pages in TabbedPage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

Is there a way to disable the swiping between TabbedPage on Android in Xamarin Forms?

XAML:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.MainTabbedPage">
</TabbedPage>
```

C#:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainTabbedPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Children.Add(new PageOne());
            Children.Add(new PageTwo());
            Children.Add(new PageThree());
        }
    }
}
```

Current behavior is that you can simply swipe to switch between the pages. But I'd like to disable that...
I found [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/409) but I can't seem to implement it in my code. Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried doing it with custom renderers ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You basically have two options: Either using Code Behind or XAML. I will describe both in this answer.

## Code Behind

When using Code Behind, you can use the `SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(bool)` extension method for any given `TabbedPage`:

```
namespace App
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainTabbedPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(false);

            Children.Add(new PageOne());
            Children.Add(new PageTwo());
            Children.Add(new PageThree());
        }
    }
}
```

## XAML

In XAML, you can set the `IsSwipePagingEnabled` property of your `TabbedPage` to `False` like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="App.MainTabbedPage"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False"
```

Additional details can be found in [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65212/disable-tabbed-page-swiping-when-using-formsappcompatactivity).

Comment: Aha, that was it. Thanx. I used `On<Android>().SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(false);` which gave me an error, and couldn't figure out what the error was...

Comment: Weird, after swiping a SwipeView on a swipe disabled TabbedPage, SetIsSwipePagingEnabled is set to true and I can swipe pages again...

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:**

You can also call the following code from your `Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage`:

```
 this.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(false);
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (still working):**

Hehe i wish i've found the answer above before i hacked into mine. Anyway, if you are using a custom renderer for a tabbed page, you can include that option there:

```
    public class MyTabbedRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {

        private TabLayout TabsLayout { get; set; }
        private ViewPager PagerLayout { get; set; }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //find the pager and tabs
            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; ++i)
            {
                Android.Views.View view = (Android.Views.View)GetChildAt(i);
                if (view is TabLayout) TabsLayout = (TabLayout)view;
                else if (view is ViewPager) PagerLayout = (ViewPager)view;
            }

            if (PagerLayout!=null) //now disable the swiping
            {
                var propertyInfo = PagerLayout.GetType().GetProperty("EnableGesture");
                propertyInfo.SetValue(PagerLayout, false, null);
            }

        }
...
```

Answer (score 7):

If your using tabbed page then this one line code works

```
namespace App
{

 public partial class MainTabbedPage : TabbedPage
 {
    public MainTabbedPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.TabbedPage.SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(this, false);

        Children.Add(new PageOne());
        Children.Add(new PageTwo());
        Children.Add(new PageThree());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Legend.
Works well and can be used with xaml pages.