# How to disable only the tab swiping and allow gesture recognizer to swipe in tab

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

As the question says, I need to enable the content page swiping which is a child of a tabbed page. But the siping for the tabbed page should be disabled.

I have gone through the various post but by using them I can able disable the swiping for the tabbed page but I am not able to use the GestureRecognizer events in children views.

I tried this: [Xamarin Forms Disable swipe between pages in TabbedPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820704/xamarin-forms-disable-swipe-between-pages-in-tabbedpage/47039814#47039814)

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Can you give some code ? Like what are your children views ? If I understood, what you are trying to achieve is some kind of carousel within a child tabbed page  ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I am looking for @Umar3x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there seems to be a bug or if not a bug a specific behavior that when you disable page swiping for the tabbed page, `gesture recognizer` won't work.

If what you want to achieve is a carousel inside a child tabbed page you can use `CarouselView` from **AlexRainMan** which works great even when `IsSwipePagingEnabled` is set to False.

https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

I have prepared a sample for you that is working on Android, did not test it on iOS :

https://github.com/vincentcastagna/TabbedPageWithCarouselView

The carousel is implemented in the AboutPage (and it is minimalist)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I will apply this :-)

Comment: This is what I am looking forward for Thank you. Can you please also tell me is there any scrolling events because I need have some functionality when user swipes the page.

Comment: Yes there is. Check the github ;)

`Scrolled: called when the carousel is transitioning from one page to another (e.NewValue = scrolling percent completed, e.Direction = scrolling direction (Left, Right, Up, Down)).`